# Field-theoretic description of fixed field of central subgroups?

Tags: galois-theory

Given a Galois extension $E/F$ with Galois group $G$, and a subextension $E/K$ with Galois group $H$, is there a "field-theoretic" characterization of when $H$ is central (i.e. $H\leq Z(G)$)? By "field-theoretic", I mean something like the characterization of $H$ being normal in $G$ as $E$ being the splitting field of some polynomial in $F[X]$.

Comment: Well, since $\,H\le Z(G)\implies H$ is normal, then you can tell *in one direction* that the subextension $\; E/K\;$ is normal...

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no such criterion (and I am a research mathematician who uses a lot of Galois theory).  Of course this means I would be delighted to hear of one...